# Qt Widget Layout Background

Tags: c++, css, qt, layout, widget

i have a layout problem in my Qt Widget

What i have:

```
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(widget1);
layout->addWidget(widget2);
layout->addWidget(widget3);
this->setLayout(layout);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7SvE.png

What i want:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANRel.png

Sorry for posting the images so sucky, but i need 10 reputation for image postings

I need the Widget 1 behind the other 2 widgets, and full sized.
It would be perfect when widget 2 and 3 could get some opacity by the stylesheet.

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create 2 Layout,

First VLayout for MainWindow and second VLayout for Widget 1

For example :

```
//If your widget1 size is null set it with setGeometry();
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(widget1);

QVBoxLayout *layoutWdg1 = new QVBoxLayout(widget1);
layoutWdg1->addWidget(widget2);
layoutWdg1->addWidget(widget3);

this->setLayout(layout);
```